# Distributing an application created in Electron/Atom Shell

Tags: electron

I want to distribute the application I developed in Electron/Atom Shell. It says on the [Electron website](http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.33.0/tutorial/application-distribution/) to change the name of the directory where the application resides to app and place it under the **Electron.app/Contents/Resources/** directory in Mac. But I cannot find that directory. I'd appreciate it if someone could help me find the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the folder is at this address:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron-prebuilt/dist/Electron.app

Once you find the Electron.app, right click on it and select show package contents. Then you can find the Contents and Resources directories.